# Export CSV with PHP and Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, fatal-error

I am using this class:

```
<?php

class csv{
private $separador;
private $cabecalho;
private $dados;
private $path;
private $arquivo;

public function csv($separador=null, $cabecalho=null, $dados="", $path="", $arquivo="csv"){
    #seta as propriedades
    $this->separador = $separador;
    $this->cabecalho = $cabecalho;
    $this->dados = $dados;
    $this->path = $path;
    $this->arquivo = $arquivo;
}
public function salvar(){
    #gera string de cabeçalho
    $colunas = "";
        foreach($this->cabecalho as $coluna){
            if ($colunas == ""){
            $colunas .= $coluna;
            } else {
            $colunas .= $this->separador.$coluna;
            }
        }
    $saida[] = $colunas;
    #gera string do corpo do arquivo
    foreach ($this->dados as $linha){
        #pega as variaveis do array
        $colunasDados = "";
        foreach($linha as $coluna){
            if ($colunasDados == ""){
            $colunasDados .= $coluna;
            } else {
            $colunasDados .= $this->separador.$coluna;
            }
        }
        $saida[] = $colunasDados;
}

    #verifica se alguma linha foi inserida
    if(count($saida)>1){
        #monta o corpo do CSV
        $corpo = implode("\n", $saida);
        #abre um arquivo para escrita, se o arquivo não existir ele tenta criar
        $fp = fopen ($this->path.$this->arquivo.".csv", "w");// W = sobrescreve
        if($fp <> NULL){
            #escreve no arquivo
            fwrite($fp, $corpo);
            #fecha o arquivo
            fclose($fp);
            #retorno do sistema
            echo "<p>Pronto</p>";
                        } 
            else {
            echo "<p>Verifique se a pasta ou o arquivo tem permissão para escrita!</p>";
                    }
     } 
      else {
        echo "<p>Sem linhas para importação!</p>";
            }
    }
```

to export the csv file.

And this is mine file that rotates:

```
 <?php
#chama classe
include("program.class.php");
$objeto = new csv();
#Executa os selects         
$tijuca = $objeto->selecionaTijuca();
#gera cabeçalho
$cabecalho = array("mes","ano","titulobanco","matricula");
#cria instancia de objeto da classe
$tijuca = new CSV (";", $cabecalho, $tijuca,"pasta/Nova/", "cotas");
$tijuca->salvar();
```

?>

I am having this problem of memory:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in .../program.class.php on line 42
```

and I've seen some solutions who have the ability to edit the php memory with this command:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","500M");
```

But it does not solve, and overloads my server.
Anyone know how do I export a csv file without overloading?
or have something in my program what is wrong?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you

Comment: try to create the file and then append data to it line by line, i think that the fatal error is being displayed because of the amount of data that you are holding the array $saida.

Comment: can you show me a example?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the postgresql [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command. It has an option to output CSV directly.

Comment: The `COPY` command is quite hard to use via a language database binding. In this case, I recommend using PHP's support for it, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-to.php

Comment: pg_copy_to fell into disuse, but i try to use and i have this mesage:
 pg_copy_to() [function.pg-copy-to]: Copy command failed: ERROR: cannot copy from view "table" HINT: Try the COPY (SELECT ...) TO variant. in

Comment: You can't use it on a view, but you can use it on a subquery, so where you would say "myview" you would say "(SELECT * FROM myview)".